# Improving the runinng time of a numerical algorithm by parallel computation, using gmpy2 module of Python

Tags: python, algorithm, multiprocessing, integer, time-complexity

I'm working on a numerical algorithm as follows.

```
import timeit
import gmpy2
import math

A = gmpy2.mpz(1000007777)
# Input a positive integer to factor.
# Put it inside the parentheses as "A = gmpy2.mpz(....)"

def factor(A):
    B = gmpy2.mpz(math.sqrt(2 * A + 0.25) - 1)
    D = gmpy2.mpz(A - (B * B + B) / 2)
    while (D > 0):
        B += 1
        D = gmpy2.mpz(A - (B * B + B) / 2)
    n = gmpy2.mpz(0)
    while (D != 0 and B <= A):
        if (D > 0):
            B += 1
            D -= B
        else:
            n += 1
            D += n
    if B > A:
        return output(0, 0, 0)
    else:
        print(f"[B={B}, n={n}]")
        if (B - n) % 2 == 0:
            E = gmpy2.mpz((B - n) / 2)
            F = gmpy2.mpz(B + n + 1)
        else:
            E = gmpy2.mpz(B - n)
            F = gmpy2.mpz((B + n + 1) / 2)
        return output(A, E, F)


def output(A, E, F):
    if A == 0:
        print(f"Initial Value Error: Reset the B value")
    else:
        if A % E != 0 or A % F != 0 or A != E * F:
            print(f"[Error Occurred]  {A}  !=  {E}  *  {F}")
        else:
            print(f"{A}  =  {E}  *  {F}")
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if A >= 2:
        timer_start = timeit.default_timer()
        factor(A)
        timer_stop = timeit.default_timer()
        running_time = round(timer_stop - timer_start, 6)
        print("running time: ", running_time, " seconds")
    else:
        print("undefined for A<2")
```

(Note that the output of *B* and *n* comes out as [B=21739322, n=21739276] with our argument in the example code)

The task of this code aims to reach 0 by adding and subtracting integers. The *D* value shall oscillate between 0 until it reaches 0. I wanted to improve the running time of this task by parallel computation, using multiprocessing module of Python.

```
import timeit
import gmpy2
import math
import multiprocessing

A = gmpy2.mpz(1000007777)
# Input a positive integer to factor.
# Put it inside the parentheses as "A = gmpy2.mpz(....)"

k = 4
# Input the number of cores to be used as "k=..."
# [!!Caveat!!] Don't use too much number of cores which exceeds the
# availability of CPU resources of your personal computer environment.
# It can damage the CPU !!!

def factor(n):
    if A < 2:
        print("undefined for A<2")
    else:
        B = gmpy2.mpz(math.sqrt(2 * A + 0.25) - 1)
        D = gmpy2.mpz(A - (B * B + B) / 2)
        while (D > 0):
            B += 1
            D = gmpy2.mpz(A - (B * B + B) / 2)
        D += gmpy2.mpz(n * (n + 1) / 2)
        while (D != 0 and B <= A):
            if (D > 0):
                B += 1
                D -= B
            else:
                D += k * n + (k * (k + 1)) / 2
                n += k
        if B > A:
            return output(0, 0, 0)
        else:
            if (B - n) % 2 == 0:
                E = gmpy2.mpz((B - n) / 2)
                F = gmpy2.mpz(B + n + 1)
            else:
                E = gmpy2.mpz(B - n)
                F = gmpy2.mpz((B + n + 1) / 2)
            return output(A, E, F)


def output(A, E, F):
    timer_stop = timeit.default_timer()
    running_time = round(timer_stop - timer_start, 6)
    if A == 0:
        print(f"Initial Value Error: Reset the B or k value \n")
    else:
        if A % E != 0 or A % F != 0 or A != E * F:
            print(f"[Error Occurred]  {A}  !=  {E}  *  {F} \n")
        else:
            print(f"[running time: {running_time} seconds]  {A}  =  {E}  *  {F} \n")
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = []
    timer_start = timeit.default_timer()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=k) as pool:
        for x in range(0, k):
            y = gmpy2.mpz(x)
            n.append(y)
        results = pool.map(factor, n)
```

The idea behind this is that, executing some addition of integers until meeting its target value, which is 0 in our code, shall be done faster if the added size of integers becomes bigger. For example, it is quite obvious that adding integers as 4+4+4... is faster to reach 100 than adding integers as 1+1+1...

However, my numerical experiments have shown that the latter code of multiprocessing module is nowhere faster than the previous code of single-core.

But, noticing that the value n=21739276 of which we mentioned above is divisible by 4, I've tried the modification of single-core version code as follows

```
import timeit
import gmpy2
import math

A = gmpy2.mpz(1000007777)
# Input a positive integer to factor.
# Put it inside the parentheses as "A = gmpy2.mpz(....)"

def factor(A):
    B = gmpy2.mpz(math.sqrt(2 * A + 0.25) - 1)
    D = gmpy2.mpz(A - (B * B + B) / 2)
    while (D > 0):
        B += 1
        D = gmpy2.mpz(A - (B * B + B) / 2)
    n = gmpy2.mpz(0)
    while (D != 0 and B <= A):
        if (D > 0):
            B += 1
            D -= B
        else:
            D += 4*n+10
            n += 4
    if B > A:
        return output(0, 0, 0)
    else:
        print(f"[B={B}, n={n}]")
        if (B - n) % 2 == 0:
            E = gmpy2.mpz((B - n) / 2)
            F = gmpy2.mpz(B + n + 1)
        else:
            E = gmpy2.mpz(B - n)
            F = gmpy2.mpz((B + n + 1) / 2)
        return output(A, E, F)


def output(A, E, F):
    if A == 0:
        print(f"Initial Value Error: Reset the B value")
    else:
        if A % E != 0 or A % F != 0 or A != E * F:
            print(f"[Error Occurred]  {A}  !=  {E}  *  {F}")
        else:
            print(f"{A}  =  {E}  *  {F}")
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if A >= 2:
        timer_start = timeit.default_timer()
        factor(A)
        timer_stop = timeit.default_timer()
        running_time = round(timer_stop - timer_start, 6)
        print("running time: ", running_time, " seconds")
    else:
        print("undefined for A<2")
```

In my computer, this made the running time to be decreased as around 3 seconds from about 4 seconds. So I concluded that the reason for the multiprocessing version code being slower is due to this part

```
else:
    D += k * n + (k * (k + 1)) / 2
    n += k
```

where the code is constantly interpreting what the argument is and translating it as an actual integer.

To avoid this, the easiest way to do is making a several code, when doing parallel computation on 4 cores, as follows.

```
else:
    D += n + 1
    n += 1
```

```
else:
    D += 2*n + 3
    n += 2
```

```
else:
    D += 3*n + 6
    n += 3
```

```
else:
    D += 4*n + 10
    n += 4
```

Among them, only the "n += 3" one will not give a desired output since it is not divisible by 4. (Recall that 4 is a divisor of n=21739276 from our original code)

If there are only 4 cases to test, then you can just make 4 copies of similar code by your hand.
However, let's think about this code

```
import timeit
import gmpy2
import math

A = gmpy2.mpz(1000007777)
# Input a positive integer to factor.
# Put it inside the parentheses as "A = gmpy2.mpz(....)"

def factor(A):
    B = gmpy2.mpz(math.sqrt(2 * A + 0.25) - 1)
    D = gmpy2.mpz(A - (B * B + B) / 2)
    while (D > 0):
        B += 1
        D = gmpy2.mpz(A - (B * B + B) / 2)
    n = gmpy2.mpz(0)
    while (D != 0 and B <= A):
        if (D > 0):
            B += 1
            D -= B
        else:
            D += 11299*n+63839350
            n += 11299
    if B > A:
        return output(0, 0, 0)
    else:
        print(f"[B={B}, n={n}]")
        if (B - n) % 2 == 0:
            E = gmpy2.mpz((B - n) / 2)
            F = gmpy2.mpz(B + n + 1)
        else:
            E = gmpy2.mpz(B - n)
            F = gmpy2.mpz((B + n + 1) / 2)
        return output(A, E, F)


def output(A, E, F):
    if A == 0:
        print(f"Initial Value Error: Reset the B value")
    else:
        if A % E != 0 or A % F != 0 or A != E * F:
            print(f"[Error Occurred]  {A}  !=  {E}  *  {F}")
        else:
            print(f"{A}  =  {E}  *  {F}")
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if A >= 2:
        timer_start = timeit.default_timer()
        factor(A)
        timer_stop = timeit.default_timer()
        running_time = round(timer_stop - timer_start, 6)
        print("running time: ", running_time, " seconds")
    else:
        print("undefined for A<2")
```

Note that 11299 is a divisor of n=21739276. Indeed, this has decreased the running time of the code from around 2 seconds from 4 seconds.

If we do the same job with subtract part

```
if (D > 0):
    B += 1
    D -= B
```

I'm sure the code shall be faster but I haven't tried this yet.

So, why do we need to do this? That is, why do we need to make multiple version of similar codes to do a task of this algorithm, instead of directly replacing the arguments with the divisor of *n*?

It is because, we don't know the *B* and *n* value before we try it.
(If you find a method to know them don't tell me, just publish it on some decent journal)

Therefore, unless we figure out any pattern of *B* and *n* values to be identified, I believe the best method at current stage is to make multiple copies of similar code to be executed.

Here is the organized question,

> Is there any way to replace the 'actual lines' inside a code by following the number of cores to be used?

For example, if there is a desired answer for the question, when there is a original code which include some lines of code as follows,

```
else:
    D += n + 1
    n += 1
```

and applying the method of desired answer shall result in copying the following codes

```
else:
    D += 2*n + 3
    n += 2
```

```
else:
    D += 3*n + 6
    n += 3
```

```
else:
    D += 4*n + 10
    n += 4
```

which do the same task, but only those lines of code have been replaced. If the number of code has been increased to 6, then we will have two more codes to be added that will concurrently executed for doing the task.

```
else:
    D += 5*n + 15
    n += 5
```

```
else:
    D += 6*n + 21
    n += 6
```

To repeat, the 'actual lines' of the code shall be replaced with another 'actual lines' since the following code

```
else:
    D += k * n + (k * (k + 1)) / 2
    n += k
```

is not that helpful for doing the exhaustive task, because of its job of interpreting what the actual argument of *k* is.

I've tried to be as specific as possible to describe my problem. If you need more elaboration please let me have a chance to elaborate the problem via comments and edits. Thank you.

**What I've tried**

I've tried to do the similar task at Java. Since Java is well known for OOP, and I thought OOP might be a promising way to solve this problem. However, the problem that Java has, it is not designed for arithmetic. I've tried the BigInteger library but it was extremely slow in my numerical test, even more than Python.

The other possible method could be doing some Scanf job by one's hand for the whole number of the sequence of code I'm going to use to. However, even assuming this method works, if the number of cores to be used increase as thousands then the method would not be considered as the best solution to this.

We've shown that

```
else:
    D += 11299*n+63839350
    n += 11299
```

this code works faster than the previous codes.  However for a bigger argument of A, we might need more than thousands, maybe millions of multi-cores, to do the task efficiently.

So I have concluded this method is not the best shot that we can try, leaving aside whether it actually works.

**Edit**

I wanted to engage on discussion as much as I can. However, because of some unfriendly behavior at the comments, I may refrain myself from doing that. (Really appreciate the answer though)

This could be my last edit in this post. I just wanted to point out, the fact that 11299 is a divisor of n=21739276 doesn't mean that we can't try more than that.

Note that n = 21739276 = 19276 (mod 30000). Then, by replacing that part of the code as follows

```
n = gmpy2.mpz(19276)
D += gmpy2.mpz(n * (n + 1) / 2)
while (D != 0 and B <= A):
    if (D > 0):
        B += 1
        D -= B
    else:
        D += 30000*n+450015000
        n += 30000
```

I could reduce the running time from around 2.4seconds to 2.1seconds. I expect the running time can be reduced more if I manipulate this subtraction part,

```
if (D > 0):
    B += 1
    D -= B
```

but I haven't tried yet. All of these elements were the motivation behind that I thought I needed to know how to do the effective parallel computation. As I said, I may not engage on further discussion unless definitely required. If you are interested, you may feel free to test and modify this code without noticing me.

Comment: A dumb successive division algorithm with no optimization factors 1000007777 in 2 seconds. Pollard's Rho in 25 milliseconds. On online algorithm (undisclosed method, probably compiled) in 80 microseconds.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is that what this is? Just factoring that number? (I stopped reading early on when they didn't say what the task is, just mysteriously called it "numerical algorithm", showed long complicated code, and showed the mysterious output "B=21739322, n=21739276").

Comment: @KellyBundy: see https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156513/16034 By the way `B-n=2.23`, where `23` is the smallest factor of `n`.

Comment: "maybe millions of multi-cores, to do the task efficiently": adding cores does not improve the efficiency of a method.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh wow, posted to at least three sites already ([here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/282273/219610), too).

Comment: @KellyBundy: with this supernatural comment: "# [!!Caveat!!] Don't use too much number of cores which exceeds the
# availability of CPU resources of your personal computer environment.
# It can damage the CPU !!!
"

Answer (score 0):

a needlessly long question, but this is python ... you can generate code at runtime if you write the function as a string, and replace the parts you need with numbers from arguments, you can `exec` the code exactly as you want, but this is not pythonic or fastest.

if your "hot loop" is limited by calculating things that can be known beforehand then it's best to just calculate them before the loop.

```py
k_local = k  # magic trick, bind the global k to a local variable k_local to make lookup faster
second_term = (k_local  * (k_local  + 1)) / 2
while (D != 0 and B <= A):
    if (D > 0):
        B += 1
        D -= B
    else:
        D += k_local * n + second_term 
        n += k_local
```

this has the **EXACT** same performance as

```py
else:
    D += 11299*n+63839350
    n += 11299
```

one thing i can recommend, is to make all variables local, (make k an argument), and use [cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/) to compile your functions to C, this way the compiler overhead is partially removed, and if you really want better performance you can use gmpy's cython "bindings" to manipulate it on C level and remove the interpreter overhead entirely (not the ABI overhead though)

if you really want to go one step further, you can rewrite this in C++ and get more performance, as gmpy is originally a C package, and you will be removing the ABI overhead, do this if you really want to squeeze the last drop of performance out of it, as your "hot loop" is probably too hot for python's virtual machine, that's trying to simulate a computer inside a computer (same to be said for java VM), rewriting this in C++ can be as much as 50 times faster than your current implementation, but the gap can be made as small as only 5 times if you use the previous suggestions.